# Else clause is running always if I remove (else code) everything working fine

Tags: jquery, if-statement

If I remove `else` part of code everything working fine even `if` statement is correct it executing `else` part also.

Why this is happening and how can I resolve this?

Please help me, I am new in JavaScript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Priject 2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label>Name:
            <input type="text" id="name">
        </label>
        <input type="submit" id="fetch">
        <br />
        <dl>

        <dt>Age</dt>
        <dd class="age">-</dd>

        <dt>Location</dt>
        <dd class="location">-</dd>

        <dt>job</dt>
        <dd class="job  ">-</dd>

        <script src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
        <script></script>
        </dl>

        <script src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
        <script>

            var people=[{
                name:"alex",
                age:20,
                location:"canada",
                job:"web developer"
            },
            {
                name:"aliana",
                age:21,
                location:"japan",
                job:"teacher"
                    }
            ]
            for(i=0;i<people.length;i++){
              result(people[i])
              }

            function result(data){
                $("#fetch").on("click",function(){
                     var name=$("#name").val();
                     if(data.name ===name ){
                        $(".age").text(" ");
                        $(".job").text(" ");
                        $(".location").text(" ");

                       $(".age").append(data.age);
                        $(".job").append(data.job);
                        $(".location").append(data.location);
                        } 
                    else if(data.name != name) {
                        $("body").text(" ")
                        noresult();
                        }
                 })


            }
            function noresult(){

            var noresult="<div><p>name is not in database </p></div>";
                $("body").append(noresult);
            }

                </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very strange calling `result()` more than once. It will add the same event handler numerous times to the same element. An explanation of what you expect this code to do would help. As it stands right now it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much everything was bad in your code. I refactored it.

> In your code, you did that :
>
> a = [1,2,3,4]
>
> input = 1
>
> loop every item in array
>
> - input = 1 ? yes => fetch and append text
> - input = 2 ? no => remove text show error
> - input = 3 ? no => remove text show error
> - input = 4 ? no => remove text show error
>
> At the end we got an error but the submitted name was a good one.

Every time you click on the button the "function" `$("#fetch").on("click",function(){` is called. Then you can do what you want in it.

*Note : use `.html()` to replace the content, not `.text("")` and then `.append(x)`.*

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Priject 2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label>Name:
            <input type="text" id="name">
        </label>
        <input type="submit" id="fetch">
        <br />
      
        <div id="result">
   <dl>
     <dt>Age</dt>
     <dd class="age">-</dd>

     <dt>Location</dt>
     <dd class="location">-</dd>

     <dt>Job</dt>
     <dd class="job">-</dd>
   </dl>       
        </div>
          
        <div id="noResult">
          <p>name is not in database </p>
        </div>

        <script>

            var people=[{
                name:"alex",
                age:20,
                location:"canada",
                job:"web developer"
            },
            {
                name:"aliana",
                age:21,
                location:"japan",
                job:"teacher"
                    }
            ]
          
          $("#noResult").hide();  
            
          $("#fetch").on("click",function(){
            var name=$("#name").val();
            // loop through each person in the array and "filter" only matching name into a new array.
            var foundPeople = people.filter(function(person){
              return name === person.name;
            });
            // name found => length = 1, not found => length = 0
            if(foundPeople.length !== 0){
              result(foundPeople[0])
            } else {
              noresult()
            }
          })
            
            function result(people){
              $(".age").text(people.age);
              $(".job").text(people.job);
              $(".location").text(people.location);
              $("#result").show();
              $("#noResult").hide();
            }

            function noresult(){
                $("#result").hide();
                $("#noResult").show();
            }

         </script>
    </body>
</html>
```